# Polymorphism - access specifier changed in derived class

Tags: java, polymorphism

Hi I just wanted to undertand the following behavior..
I have defined the same method - gg() in the base and derived class with different access

```
Class Base  
{  
// some thing   
**private** Integer gg(){  
 //return something   
 }  
}

Class Derived{  
// something  
**public** Integer gg(){  
//return something  
}  
}
```

In my main method when I initialize a variable

```
  Base d = new Derived()
```

and attempt to call d.gg() it says Base.gg() is private. Does modifying the access specifier make the method calls revert to the Base class method?. When i change the access specifer of gg() in base class to public,  then it calls the method in Derived class just as polymorphism should.

From what I read about polymorphism, its ok to make the access specifier less restrictive in derived class which was the case here .

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Accessing an object through a reference-to-base-class means that you intend to access it via the interface specified by the base class.  If you've declared a method `private` in the base class, then you can't access it via a reference-to-base!

Consider the absurdity that would ensue if that weren't the case:

```
Base b;

if (some condition) {
    b = new Base();
}
else {
    b = new Derived();
}

b.ggg();  // Ok, or not?
```

Comment: The object d in my post stores a reference to the derived class right? so does the variable type determine the access for a method and not the actual object it is referring to?.

Answer (score 2):

In Java private members of a super class are **not** visible in derived classes. Because of that it is **not possible** in a derived class to:

- *reference private members of a super class* - they are there but you just can't acces them, they are inner details of a super class which are not meant to be used in derived classes,
- *override private methods*.

So in your example `Derived.gg()` method is not overriding the `Base.gg()` method. `Derived.gg()` is just a method with the same name as the method in `Base` class but they have nothing in common. There is also no name clash because `Derived` class is not aware of a `Base.gg()` method.

Comment: It's not that they're not *inherited*, it's just that they aren't *visible* from the derived class.

Comment: @Oli Charlesworth, you are right. I wasn't specific enoguht - I changed my wording.

Answer (score 0):

If you know c#, this answer will be obvious. First runtime will check the signature of parent method to see if it is virtual, then look at the child same signature method. if you can not check parent method (here private), you wiil stop at first step